Change style of True/False everywhere
I was wondering if it was possible to change the output of Booleans, (True and False) so that they are always displayed in StandardForm with green and red colour.

I suspect there may be something in the SystemFiles that does it but I couldn't manage to find the right spot.
Any help is appreciated.

Another alternative:
MakeBoxes[True, StandardForm] := 
  StyleBox["True", StripOnInput -> True, 
   Background -> Green];
MakeBoxes[False, StandardForm] := 
  StyleBox["False", StripOnInput -> True, 
   Background -> Red];

The assignments can be Unset:
MakeBoxes[True, StandardForm] =.;
MakeBoxes[False, StandardForm] =.;


Ah, I figured it could be done directly with MakeBoxes. Wasn't sure how so I defaulted to using the Notation package.

@GlennWelch The way to "cheat" at this is to examine the cell expression of Style[True, Background -> Green]. Tx.

Something along these lines should work for your purposes.


$Post = ReplaceAll[{True -> Style[True, Background -> Green], 
   False -> Style[False, Background -> Red]}]

or avoiding messing with Graphics (but still other things can be affected so it is up to OP to specify exact conditions)
$Post = If[Head[#] === Graphics, #, 
    ReplaceAll[#, {True -> Style[True, Background -> Green], 
      False -> Style[False, Background -> Red]}]] &;

Removing styling:
$Post =.


This will come handy: StripOnInput -> True

This is a bad idea, as it will have many unwanted side-effects, for example in plotting: Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}].

@Domen We do not know exact OP's purpose, maybe it is sufficient for OP. If not there always can be added condition like If[Head[#] === Graphics, #, ReplaceAll....
